# Is there a way to append some function to initialize and execute it?

Tags: ruby, methods, extend

Let's say I have a class Test

```
class Test
  def initialize()
    puts "cool"
  end
end
```

Is there a way to extend initialize class somehow and execute some method in it?

For example I want to:

```
class Test
  def func()
    puts "test"
  end
end

test = Test.new()
```

Should output

```
cool
test
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is. But this feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you solving with this?

Comment: There's an existing module and a class in it. 
I want to extend it's initialize class to additionally call my custom method in it.

Comment: Ok, but why? There's usually a better way than altering an existing class.

Comment: @Schwern, "why" is a valid question but at the same time I've learned a lot by answering far crazier questions, taken at face value.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why not both?

Comment: @Schwern, that's what I said. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a module containing your extension:

```
module TestExtension
  def initialize
    super
    puts 'test'
  end
end
```

and then [`prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Module.html#method-i-prepend) that module to `Test`:

```
class Test
  def initialize
    puts 'cool'
  end
end

Test.prepend(TestExtension)
Test.new
# cool
# test
```

Answer (score 2):

If the code for `Test` is not under your control, and you want to inject `test`:

```
Test.class_eval do
  def test
    puts "TEST"
  end

  alias initialize_without_test initialize

  # This, if you want the return value of `test` to replace the original's    
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    initialize_without_test(*args, &block)
    test
  end

  # Or this, if you want to keep the return value of original `initialize`
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    initialize_without_test(*args, &block).tap do
      test
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Return value of initializer is ignored, though.

Comment: Ah, they want to `puts` (or other side-effects). That's easier. Thought they want the return value.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `initialize` is only called for its side-effects. The return value isn't used.

Comment: @Stefan: yes, I know. Wasn't sure OP knows too. I've seen such questions before ("how to change return value of initialize", thinking that would affect what `new` returns)

Comment: @Stefan ...when called by `::new`. There is no reason (except code stink) that it couldn’t also be called explicitly by someone, who would examine the return value, as if it were a normal instance method (which it actually is). Obviously this is extremely hypothetical, but not as impossible as you suggest.

Comment: What is the advantage of this over simply using `Module#prepend`, which was more or less explicitly created to make this unnecessary?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Not much. In my defense, my answer was earlier than Stefan’s, I didn’t think of it, wish I did, upvoted him anyway; decided to leave this up because it does showcase the pre-`prepend` way (and Ruby’s flexibility).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't understand your point. Before your comment Amadan had made no claim that his answer is superior to using `prepend`. His reply to you makes it clear that after "prepend" came to mind he realised that was the way to go. Does that mean he should now delete his answer? Of course not. Who knows how readers may benefit in future by having read his answer. Moreover, I think this answer helps readers understand why `prepend` is useful, which has value in itself.